# Demonstrate the derivative of the exponential matrix via the generalized definition of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to do exactly what the question says.

Given a function $f:U\mapsto\Bbb{R}^m$, where $U $ is an open subet of $\Bbb{R}^n$. The derivative of $f$ at is defined by the linear transformation of $h$, $L(x)$ that satisfies:

$$\lim_{\vert\vert{h}\vert\vert\to 0}\frac{\vert\vert f(x+h)-f(x)-L(x)h \vert\vert}{\vert\vert h\vert\vert}=0$$

In the case of the matrix exponential function we have $f:\Bbb{R}\mapsto\Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $f(x)=e^{Ax}$, the definition when checking $L=Ae^{Ax}$ yields:

$$\lim_{\vert\vert{h}\vert\vert\to 0}\frac{\vert\vert e^{A(x+h)}-e^{Ax}-Ae^{Ax}h \vert\vert}{\vert\vert h\vert\vert}=0$$

But I don't really know what else to do from this point forward, since I'm not very familiar with the length $(\vert\vert x \vert\vert)$ operator (I know its definition). I would like for anyone to help me finish this demonstration, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}e^{A(x+h)} - e^{Ax} - Ae^{Ax} h
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{A^k(x+h)^k}{k!} - \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{A^k x^k}{k!} - h\sum_{m \ge 0} \frac{A^{m+1} x^m}{m!}
\\
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{A^k(x+h)^k}{k!} - \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{A^k x^k}{k!} - h\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{A^k x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
\\
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{A^k}{k!} [(x+h)^k - x^k - k h x^{k-1}]
\end{align}

Expand $(x+h)^k$ and subtract the other two terms to get a quantity that is of the order $O(h^2)$. This is fast enough to vanish even when dividing by the $|h|$ in the denominator.